# In Hulk Hogan vs Gawker Media, how did plaintiff pierce the corporate veil?

Tags: litigation

In the recent case of Hulk Hogan vs Gawker Media, company founder Nick Denton was ordered to pay $10,000,000 personally.

How specifically did plaintiff pierce the corporate veil?

Comment: Where is Gawker Media LLC domiciled?  The corporate laws of that state likely figure prominently in the answer to this.  Also can you provide links or references to the case and the verdict ordering the founder to pay damages *personally*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gawker, Denton, and many others](https://assets.documentcloud.org/documents/2111332/hogans-amended-complaint.pdf) including different Gawker "companies" are defendants as you see in the complaint. After the verdict, 3 defendants (Gawker LLC, Denton, Daulerio) moved for "[judgment notwithstanding verdict](http://www.litigationandtrial.com/files/2016/05/Gawker-Motion-for-JNOV.pdf)" on all claims against all defendants, also [they moved for a new trial](http://www.litigationandtrial.com/files/2016/05/Gawker-Motion-for-New-Trial.pdf). On p. 27 of the latter it indicates that punes were awarded against Gawker, Denton, and Daulerio (the [verdict document](http://hpc.pinellasclerk.org/hpcdisplay/Documents/26029684-1.tif) indicate this as well). The megapile of documents is [here](http://hpc.pinellasclerk.org/hpcdisplay/default.cshtml?page=1). So they didn't pierce the veil, they skewered everybody in the room.